# Problem remembering the exact name/word/term

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, programming, philosophy

I'm looking for a name/word for when someone asks and seeks advice for a problem but, instead of telling you the real issue or the problem, s/he attempts to seek help to make her own solution work.

For example:  "I need to tie a rope around a building so it won't tip over.  How can I make it strong enough?" [Real problem is the building foundation]

I'm from the computer programming background and I use to see that a lot in StackOverflow Q/A ...but I can't remember the name of it...something like A-B problem. Does anyone know the exact name?

Comment: That would be [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @WeatherVane For love of goodness.  Thank you!!  Put that as an answer and I will be more glad to accept it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is it called when someone asks a question but it's not really root/true question they have?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/519894/what-is-it-called-when-someone-asks-a-question-but-its-not-really-root-true-que) Or [expression for asking a question in a way that assumes a certain solution?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/131963/expression-for-asking-a-question-in-a-way-that-assumes-a-certain-solution/234669#234669)?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes sir.  Exactly.

Comment: Then please don't accept another answer to the same question. ELU tries to avoid bloat.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth it appears (at least to me), that Weather Vane answer is more authoritative and complete.

Comment: @Zuzlx my answer adds nothing to the revealed dups, one of them also links to the same post. If you un-accept it the question can be closed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is called [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem. This leads to enormous amounts of wasted time and energy, both on the part of people asking for help, and on the part of those providing help.

---

Also from [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) on a sister site Stackoverflow:

> The XY problem is asking about your attempted solution rather than your actual problem.
>
> That is, you are trying to solve problem X, and you think solution Y would work, but instead of asking about X when you run into trouble, you ask about Y.

Comment: A multi-duplicate.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I can't delete it unless it is de-accepted. Your dup suggestion wasn't quite quick enough.